# Como validar o IP de uma lista Emails para saber se são reais ou falsos e se podem receber mensagem?

Tags: php, email, validação, ip, filter

Sei que existem serviços que fazem isso, mas gostaria de saber como eles fazem esse tipo de teste, para descobrir se o e-mail é realmente válido, não só através de um filtro do PHP, como por exemplo:

```
function validEmail($email) {
   if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false) {
       return true;
   } 
   return false;
}

$listaEMails = array(
   'fakemail@gmail',
   'emailvdd@uol.com.br',
   'seu_mail@terra.com.br',
   'fakemail@terra.com.br',
);

foreach($listaEMails as $k => $email) {
   if (!validEmail($email)) {
       unset($listaEMails[$k]);
   }
}

echo "Emails verdadeiros: <pre>";
print_r($listaEMails);
```

Mas utilizando algum ping via servidor que verifica o IP, tipo:

```
@servidor.com.br (IP: 200.123.432.231)
```

Não sei se isso funciona de fato:

```
$domain = array_pop(explode("@", $email));

filter_var(gethostbyname($domain), FILTER_VALIDATE_IP);
```

ou

```
checkdnsrr($domain, "MX");
```

Penso que poderia ser algo do tipo, mas uma forma que fizesse ping no servidor?

```
function nsLookupPing($domain) {
 $app  ="nslookup $domain";
 exec($app, $result);
 if ($result[5] == '' || !isset($result[5])) {
     return false;
 }
 return true;
 }
```

> **Editado a partir daqui:**

A resposta do @ederwander solucionou meio caminho, o que não estou conseguindo, é capturar essa saída que ele falou, veja no exemplo abaixo, estou fazendo a seguinte requisição GET: `validator.php?email=meuemail@gmail.com`, usando a seguinte classe que montei:

```
class ValidateEmail
{

    private $email;
    private $domain;
    private $socket;

    public function __construct($email)
    {

       $this->email  = $email;
       $domain  = @array_pop(explode("@", $email));
       $this->domain = $domain;
    }

    private function pesoExchanger($a, $b)
    {
        return $a["exchanger_num"] - $b["exchanger_num"];
    }

    private function validEmail()
    {
       if (filter_var($this->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false) {
           return true;
       } 
       return false;
    }

    public function getDomain()
    {
        return $this->domain;
    }

    public function getMail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function nsLookupPing()
    {

        if (!$this->validEmail()) {
            //retorna falso, e a mensagem de email inválido
            return array('status'=> false, 'msg' => 'Email inválido');
        }
        //captura o domínio do email
        $domain = $this->getDomain();
        //verifica se o domínio é válido numa conexão do tipo MX
        exec("nslookup -type=mx {$domain}", $result);

        if (!isset($result[4])) {
           //se não houver um retorno válido na linha 4, significa que ele não é um domínio válido
           return array('status'=> false, 'msg' => 'Email com domínio inválido');
        }

        if ($result[4] == '' || preg_match('/No answer/', $result[4])) {
           //se não houver um retorno válido na linha 4, mesmo sendo setado, ele enviará uma resposta de erro 
            return array('status'=> false, 'msg' => 'Email com domínio inválido, motivo: '.$result[4]);
        } 
       //aqui continua para a fase de validação (conforme explicação de: @ederwander)
       $exchanger_num = array();
       //copia o array para uma outra variável e retira as 4 primeiras linhas 
       $n_results = $result;
       unset($n_results[0]);
       unset($n_results[1]);
       unset($n_results[2]);
       unset($n_results[3]);
       //verifica se mesmo removendo as 4 linhas, ainda existe 1 ou mais hosts
       if (!count($n_results)) {
          return array('status'=> false, 'msg' => "Erro de E-mail inválido! Não há um 'mail exchanger' definido para nenhum peso.");
       }
       // faz um laço pegando todos os hosts que contiverem um peso exchanger
       foreach ($n_results as $k => $result_exchanger) {
           if (preg_match('/ exchanger = /', $result_exchanger)) {
              //captura o conteúdo original do servidor e o valor após o exchange
               list($srv_original, $restante) = explode(' exchanger = ', $result_exchanger);
              //quebra nos espaços 
              $first = explode(' ',$restante);
              //remove a informação mail de exchange capturando o primeiro servidor de entrada
              $original_srv  = str_replace('    mail','', $srv_original);
              //lista todos os servidores com seus respectivos pesos
              $srv = $result[4];
              $exchanger_num[] = array(
                                        'srv_original'  => $original_srv ,
                                        'srv_fornecido' => @array_pop(explode(' ',$srv)),
                                        'exchanger_num' => (int) $first[0]
                                 );
           }
       }
      //ordena pelo menor peso 
      usort($exchanger_num, array($this, "pesoExchanger"));

      $other_exchangers = $exchanger_num;
      unset($other_exchangers[0]);
      //retorna todos os servidores, deixando o mais leve como preferido
      return array(
                   'light_exchanger'  => $exchanger_num[0],
                   'other_exchangers' => $other_exchangers,
                   'status'           => true,
                   'msg'              => 'Servidor de e-mail válido'
      );
    } 

    private function extractExchangerLightEmail()
    {
       $data = $this->nsLookupPing();
       if (isset($data['light_exchanger']) && $data['status']) {
          return $data['light_exchanger'];
       }
    }

    public function verifyNSLookupPing()
    {
         //extrai o servidor com peso mais leve
         $data  = $this->extractExchangerLightEmail();
         //verifica se há um servidor fornecido
         if (isset($data['srv_fornecido'])) {
             $host = $data['srv_fornecido'];
             //verifica para ver se existe um cliente de email válido através de um socket tcp, na porta 25
             $fp = stream_socket_client("tcp://{$host}:25", $errno, $errstr, 30);
             if (!$fp) {
               //se ocorrer erro, retorna uma exceção
               return array('status' => false, 'msg'=>"O servidor do E-mail é inválido, erro: $errstr ($errno)");
          } else {
            $result = $this->socketValidation($host, 25);
            if($result) {
               return array('status' => $result['status'], 'msg'=>$result['msg']);
            }
          }

       } 
     return array('status' => false, 'msg'=>"Não ocorreu uma conexão para o Servidor do e-mail");
    }

    private function socketValidation($host, $port = 25)
    {

        $address = gethostbyname($host); 

        $command = "ping -c 1 " . $address;  
        $r = exec($command);  
          if ($r[0]=="r") {        
            $this->socket = socket_create (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
            if ($this->socket < 0) { 
                $status = false;
                $msg = "Falha de socket: " . socket_strerror($this->socket); 
            } else { 
                $status = true;
                $msg = "O servidor de e-mail é válido!";
            } 
          return array('status' => $status,
                      'msg'     => $msg 
               );
          } else {
             return array('status' =>false,
                      'msg'    => "Não foi possível criar um socket para testar o servidor" 
               );
          }

    }
}

$email = $_GET['email'];

if (isset($email)) {
    $verifyMail = new ValidateEmail($email);
    $saida = $verifyMail->verifyNSLookupPing();
    var_dump($saida);
}
```

Só no terminal que aparece essa saída, acredito que isso seja um valor privado:

```
220 mx.google.com ESMTP j11si51572042qgd.1 - gsmtp
```

Comment: Validar IP de uma lista de emails ? ou saber se um determinado endereço de email existe ??

Comment: Não, validar se o e-mail pode receber mensagem, se ele existe e se o servidor existe?

Comment: Gostaria de saber se tem como fazer um ping no email (tipo enviar alguma coisa e receber uma resposta), sem ter que enviar uma mensagem.

Comment: `exec("telnet {$host} 25", $result_telnet)` isso não é o modo correto de se fazer, como você vai enviar o resto dos comandos? como vai pegar o retorno de cada linha?, Você tem que trabalhar puramente com sockets no seu código para poder enviar e pegar cada retorno esperado....

Comment: outro detalhe vc está procurando `Connected to`, não existe esta mensagem no retorno do telnet para o gmail...

Comment: Ainda não tenho uma validação do "email" em si, somente do servidor.

Comment: @IvanFerrer não existe validação segura de email sem ser enviando e monitorando retorno. E mesmo fazendo isso, ainda pode ter alguns casos extremos de falha.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok eu posso ensinar, use para o bem, mas isso me cheira SPAM :-(

Realmente existem meios de checar se um email é válido, todo servidor de email precisa ter um [MX](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mx_record) cadastrado no `DNS` para poder receber mensagens, portanto qualquer um pode consultar por qual `MX` determinado domínio responde, vamos testar com o gmail, em solo linux ou windows(CMD), digite `nslookup`:

você vai ter a seguinte saída:

```
C:\Users\Eder>nslookup
Servidor PadrÒo:  xxxxx
Address:  8.8.8.8
```

Perfeito vamos agora definir qual tipo de consulta queremos efetuar, então digite: `set type=MX`  logo depois digite por exemplo `gmail.com`, estamos falando para consultar quais são as entradas `MX` cadastrados para o `gmail`, fiz aqui tive a seguinte resposta:

```
> set type=MX
> gmail.com
Servidor:  xxxxxxxxxxx
Address:  8.8.8.8

Não é resposta autoritativa:
gmail.com       MX preference = 20, mail exchanger = alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
gmail.com       MX preference = 40, mail exchanger = alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
gmail.com       MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
gmail.com       MX preference = 5, mail exchanger = gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
gmail.com       MX preference = 30, mail exchanger = alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com

gmail.com       nameserver = ns4.google.com
gmail.com       nameserver = ns1.google.com
gmail.com       nameserver = ns3.google.com
gmail.com       nameserver = ns2.google.com
ns1.google.com  internet address = 216.239.32.10
ns2.google.com  internet address = 216.239.34.10
ns3.google.com  internet address = 216.239.36.10
ns4.google.com  internet address = 216.239.38.10
>
```

OK ai está, eles possuem várias entradas `MX`, Se fosse um domínio que não existisse ou não tivesse `MX` cadastrado não haveria resposta, mas repare que cada registro `MX` possui um peso diferente, vamos pegar qualquer um deles por exemplo o que tem menor peso, neste caso `5` respondendo pelo seguinte endereço `gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com`

Podemos agora fazer uma conexão na porta de envio(25) de email deste servidor e enviar alguns comandos por telnet, vaja um exemplo real:

```
C:\Users\Eder>telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
```

após isso você vai receber a seguinte tela:

```
220 mx.google.com ESMTP j11si51572042qgd.1 - gsmtp
```

pois bem comece a digitar comandos, (os comandos precisam ser exatos, não pode errar e apagar dentro desta conexao telnet)

```
helo hi
```

como retorno você vai ter:

```
250 mx.google.com at your service
```

Gostei da mensagem deles lol, agora digite qualquer endereço mesmo que não exista:

```
mail from: <youremail@gmail.com>
```

terá o seguinte retorno:

```
250 2.1.0 OK j11si51572042qgd.1 - gsmtp
```

por fim digite o email que quer verificar se existe neste domínio:

```
RCPT TO:<playingwithtelnet@gmail.com>
```

o retorno será:

```
250 2.1.5 OK j11si51572042qgd.1 - gsmtp
```

Pronto um `OK`  bem grande...

se a consulta for para um endereço q não existe o retorno de erro `550`:

Segue todo o processo de um email válido:

```
220 mx.google.com ESMTP j11si51572042qgd.1 - gsmtp
helo hi
250 mx.google.com at your service
mail from: <youremail@gmail.com>
250 2.1.0 OK j11si51572042qgd.1 - gsmtp
RCPT TO:<playingwithtelnet@gmail.com>250 2.1.5 OK j11si51572042qgd.1 - gsmtp
```

E agora para um email que não existe:

```
220 mx.google.com ESMTP q66si687813qgd.93 - gsmtp
helo hi250 mx.google.com at your service
mail from: <youremail@gmail.com>250 2.1.0 OK q66si687813qgd.93 - gsmtp
RCPT TO:<lokokokoko@gmail.com>550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos
```

Demonstrei como fazer isso no braço, é óbvio que a "galera" desenvolveu sistemas que conectam via socket na porta `25` e enviam os comandos ...

Comment: +1, e vale lembrar que atualmente os serviços de SMTP podem não confirmar na hora se um endereço existe ou não, e justamente isso é usado para combater spam. O OK reconhece o mero recebimento da mensagem, mas não serve como prova de existência do usuário (nestes casos, o servidor aceita, mas retorna um email dizendo que não existe o endereço).

Comment: Isso mesmo @Bacco o chamado greylist :-)

Comment: Só de curiosidade, uma informação extra: o MX é dispensável quando existe um serviço de email no A ou AAAA (apesar de eu considerar essa "economia de DNS" uma prática extrermamente porca, ela existe).